# Find an integrable function - Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I have a following problem

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{n^3x}{n^4+x^4} dx
$$

And I would like to show that I can switch an integral and a limit. So I think, that I should use Lebesgue`s dominated convergence theorem, but I am not able to find any integrable function $g(x)$ such that:

$$
|f_n(x)| \leq g(x) 
$$

Please could you help me to find this function?

Thank you so much.

Comment: what is the problem with that integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can't exchange the limit and the integral:

On the one hand,
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,\ \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{n^3x}{n^4+x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x=n\frac\pi4,$$
hence
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{n^3x}{n^4+x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x=+\infty$$
but on the other hand,
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_+,\ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n^3x}{n^4+x^4}=0,$$
hence
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n^3x}{n^4+x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x=0.$$

Comment: Thank you, so it makes sense that I was not able to confirm assumptions for Lebesgue's theorems.

Comment: @Stats123: you cannot confirm them because they clearly do not hold: at $x=n$, the function $\frac{n^3 x}{n^4+x^4}$ equals $\frac{1}{2}$, so there is no dominating integrable function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In that case the parameter is $n$, thus it is enough is to study the function $h_x(y) = \frac{y^3x}{y^4+x^4}$ and find a good upper bound on $[a,\infty)$ for some $a$ ($h_x(y) \to 0$).

The usual method of deriving $h_x$ to find its maximum works.

Comment: I find the supremum, which is for $ y= x*\sqrt[4]{3}$ and if I plug it to the function it is not integrable

Answer (score 1):

Without Lebesgue theorems (dominated/monotone convergence):

You could try for example

$$\int\frac{n^3x}{n^4+x^4}dx=\frac1{n^4}\int\frac{n^3x}{1+\left(\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^2}dx=\frac n2\int\frac{\frac{2x}{n^2}}{1+\left(\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^2}dx=\frac n2\arctan\frac{x^2}{n^2}+K$$

and now, using l'Hospital with a continuous variable $\;n\;$ :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\arctan\frac{x^2}{n^2}}{\frac2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{2x^2}{n^3}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{x^4}{n^4}}}{-\frac2{n^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3x^2}{n^4+x^4}=0\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in (,\infty)$$

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks good, but I have to use Lebesgue theorems.

Comment: You can use the above anyway as a supporting argument...and knowing the result is zero can help you out.

Comment: I was able to do that, but 1 is not integrable close to infinity

Comment: @Stats123 What does $\;1\;$ have to do with this?? You'd show your function is eventually less than a very integrable function in $\;(0,\infty)\;$ : $\;\frac1{1+x^3}\;$ ...

Comment: sorry I did read it properly at the first time

Comment: @DonAntonio: your result is wrong: in the last sentence when you claim _the last inequality is easily provable for any positive $x$ and for any $n>N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$:_ the problem is that given an $N$, $x$ can only be in a bounded set for the inequality to be true. So the domination condition fails.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I think you're right, thanks. Deleting that part.

Comment: This answer is not useful. Since Lebesgue conditions are not met, there is no point in computing pointwise limits. By simply using the substitution $x=n z$ in the innermost integral, it is trivial that the answer **is not** zero, it is $+\infty$.